# Prove that $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ are not equivalent norms on $C[0, 1]$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the sequence $f_n(x) = x^n$. Then $\|f_n\|_1 = \frac{1}{n+1}$, and $\|f_n\|_2= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$

How do you get from $f_n(x) = x^n$ to  $\|f_n\|_1 = \frac{1}{n+1}$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What is the definition of $\Vert \cdot \Vert_1$? Of $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$?

Answer (score 1):

In your case,
$$\|f\|_1=\int_0^1 |f(t)|dt,$$
and
$$\|f\|_2=\sqrt{\int_0^1 |f(t)|^2dt}.$$

Comment: I know but in this case ,how integral x^n get into 1/n+1

Comment: The primitive function of $x^n$ is $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ !

Comment: thank you so much!